# Transpose not in list of Commands in customize Ribbon and Toolbar in Excel

Tags: ms-office

I want to add the Transpose button to the Quick Access Toolbar but I can't find it in the list of Commands.   Is it there? [image: All the TR commands]

I'm on Excel version 16.38

Comment: I think it's only available when you do a Paste.  You'd have to build a macro using it and then put that macro in the ribbon as a button.

Comment: Hmm, I tried making a macro with transpose but running it gave me an error. ( not helpful without details, I know. Maybe a different question)